# How to make sure a steam key I redeem yields me the uncensored, not the German edition?

Tags: steam, region-lock

I want to buy the games offered in the current Humble Weekly Sale. What do I have to do in order to get the uncensored version? In particular, is the country of purchase defined by where the IP I order the bundle from or the one from which I redeem the Steam keys I get?

Also, is it necessary to change the download region in Steam?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's against the Steam EULA to change your download region to a region you're not actually in just to get around legal restrictions that apply to your actual region...

Comment: I think the purpose of the download region is just to choose a server that is close to your location. Also I just read the relevant parts and they don't mention anything about that.

Comment: @Shadur that's incorrect, the files you get are determined by what edition of the game you own, not where you download it from.

Comment: @kotekzot Not really, with the same account I created in Germany, I could download the uncensored versions of the same game in South Africa, and in Turkey. It's the via IP determined geographic location that counts at the moment of purchase.

Comment: @Bora that's pretty much what I said.

Comment: Fair enough. Downvote withdrawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change your download region, because the files you get are determined by what edition of the game you own, not where you download it from. To get an international key from Humble Bundle, you need to use an IP address that isn't associated with Germany or other countries that censor a particular game. You can do that via proxies or, better yet, asking a friend from another country to gift you the Bundle. Using a proxy may not help if you pay with a German credit card, though.

The key itself determines whether you get a censored version or not, though some games might provide additional complications - being unable to activate them or download an activated game while in Germany or other country with mad censorship laws - that sort of thing is normally noted on a game's Steam store page under the screenshot slider.

Source: I've been gifted a Humble Bundle copy of Titan Quest that was bought in Germany, and had to spend a month arguing with Steam Support to get them to remove the game so I could redeem my international key for that game.

Comment: Getting an international key might not be sufficient, the SR3 international key from the Humble Bundle was not redeemable in Steam from Germany.

Comment: -1 for the proxy and this should not be further upvoted. Using a proxy or any other sort of tunneling protocol can lead to a permanent ban of your Steam account. I highly advise anybody reading this not to try it.

Comment: @user28015 &kotekzot, let's be friendly here, please :)  If you disagree, downvoting and leaving a polite comment should suffice.

Comment: Most stores use the IP address to locate your region and can be worked around with VPN or proxy. Humble Bundle however does not. I am not sure how they get the country, might be CC or Paypal info, could also be that they hardcore the country to your account instead of using your connected IP address thus a fresh account might work. Either way, it's more complicated then just a VPN/proxy.